# Fill an existing LibreOffice document with values from the command line

Tags: bash, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I run a bash script which generates a PDF at the end of a billing run. I used to do that with LaTeX but the users ask for a more MS Office like solution. So I'm thinking of using a LibreOffice document and use LibreOffice on the command line to generate the PDF. That works. But I have no idea how to inject the values I need to change (e.g. the address and the billing information) into that document before I can generate a PDF.

Let's assume the `example.odt` document contains this text:

```
Dear $fist_name,

you own us $amount USD.

Regards
xyz
```

Since `example.odt` is not really easy to edit from a Bash script I'm searching for an other way to inject values for `$first_name` and `$amount`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You mentioned a prior LaTeX solution which might be a valuable addition to your post.

Comment: You might start by realizing that an ODT file is just a ZIP file. Ergo, you can unzip it with a command like `unzip -x mydoc.odt`.  The content is in an XML-file named content.xml.

Comment: With the way odt files are formatted, theres no guarantee that text will stay together if you unzip it and edit the content.xml manually.  Sometimes it works, but it's kind of flaky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LibreOffice file is a zip archive which can be unzipped with

```
unzip old.odt -d example
cd example
```

The content of the file is in the file `content.xml`. There is can be changed with `sed` or any other tool. After that the `.odt` file has to be created again:

```
zip -r ../new.odt .
```

After that the PDF can be created with this command (the path is from OS X):

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless 
--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir ~/Desktop/ ~/Desktop/new.odt
```